# Force all subplots to use the same axis range when plotting with Pandas

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I'm using the "by" option to create facet plots with Pandas like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(randn(1000)).hist(by=randint(0, 4, 1000), figsize=(6, 4))
```

[image]

Which is great. However I want both the x and y axis to be the same across all plots. Is there a built in way to do this? In ggplot I would use the `scales="fixed"` option but I don't see something like that built into the Pandas plotting.

Obviously my fallback is to write a few short lines that does this for me, but if there's an automagic way to do this, I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for shared x- and y-axes which can be enabled by passing `sharex=True` and `sharey=True` as [keyword arguments to `hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html).

This creates the subplots via `matplotlib`'s subplot machinery. The upside of this as opposed to manually positioning subplots and removing axes is that you can use a large `matplotlib` toolset to manipulate the axes, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(randn(1000)).hist(by=randint(0, 4, 1000), figsize=(6, 4),
                            sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
```

[image: example with some axis properties set]

Comment: as a side note, it appears there's currently (Sept 2014) a bug in Pandas plotting where hist breaks with by if the number of plots does not fully fill a row. For example: `pd.Series(randn(1000)).hist(by=randint(0, 5, 1000), sharex=True, sharey=True)`

I've opened an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8256